# How to setContent in activity after first time require permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-jetpack-compose

I have tried to require permission in activity and then get the function of compose, but when i first time get the permission, it can not directly get the content of compose.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            // the setContent code not executed after getting the permission first time
            setContent {
                MyTheme {
                    Main(
                        viewModel = viewModel,
                        backDispatcher = onBackPressedDispatcher
                    )
                }
            }
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }
    }

    private fun allPermissionsGranted() = REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS.all {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            baseContext, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    companion object {
        private const val REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10
        private val REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Activities do not get recreated after a permission grant. So, in your case, nothing will happen in the app after the permission grant. This is unrelated to Compose; you would get the same behavior with `setContentView()` where you have `setContent {}`.

Move your `setContent {}` logic into a different function. Call it from `onCreate()` where you have it now. And, override `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, and call that function from there if you were granted permission.

A more Compose-y way would be to `remember` whether you have permission and update that state from `onRequestPermissionsResult()` if you were granted permission. Do all that from *inside* `setContent()`, and Compose will recompose on the state change.

Comment: If i deny the permission, the `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` will not be executed again. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @ccd: `requestPermissions()` will be executed again if you arrange to execute it. You might do that based on user input, or you might `finish()` your activity with a "sorry!" `Toast` and try again if the user re-launches your app.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can achieve it by using fragments.
You should check permission, request and handle response

If permission granted -> navigate to the fragment

If permission not granted wait until user grants and upon response -> navigate to the fragment